# How to run Task Scheduler even when it is idle

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-8, vbscript, scheduled-tasks

In MS Window 8 (PC), using Task Scheduler, I made a weekly task that is supposed to kick-off every Wed/Sat 10:00pm.

However, when the PC is idle (Screen saver is on), the task just cannot start.

But the task can start when I lock the PC (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>).

Any idea on what I missed in the set-up? I already disabled below options in tab `Condition`:

- `Start the task only if the computer is idle for:`
- `Wait for idle for:`

Any idea on what I missed in the set-up?

Comment: An interesting question but, in my opinion, should belong at [su]. Voting to migrate.

Comment: Normally there shouldn't be a difference between "idle" and "locked". Do task history and/or eventlog provide any clues?

Answer (score 0):

On the General tab, in the "Security options" section, the "Run whether user is logged on or not" option should be selected.  I hope that helps.